# Class Delegate does not implement protocol

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I`m doing something wrong here but I can't figure out what it is .

**AppDelegate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    UIScrollView *scrollView;
    UIPageControl *pageControl;
    NSMutableArray *viewControllers;
    UIView *flipside;

    // To be used when scrolls originate from the UIPageControl
    BOOL pageControlUsed;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *flipside;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *viewControllers;

- (IBAction)showInfo:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)changePage:(id)sender;

@end
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (IBAction)showInfo:(id)sender {    

    FlipsideViewController *controller = [[FlipsideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlipsideView" bundle:nil];
    controller.delegate = self;

    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

    [controller release];
}
```

This is where I`m getting :
**warning: class 'AppDelegate' does not implement the 'FlipsideViewControllerDelegate' protocol.**

After line :
*controller.delegate = self;*

My FlipsideViewController.h looks like this :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol FlipsideViewControllerDelegate;


@interface FlipsideViewController : UIViewController {
    id <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender;
@end


@protocol FlipsideViewControllerDelegate
- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(FlipsideViewController *)controller;
@en
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's exactly what the error message says. `AppDelegate` just doesn't implement the protocol. In your header file, add `FlipsideViewControllerDelegate` between the brackets (i.e. `<UIApplicationDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate, FlipsideViewControllerDelegate>`), and implement the `-flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:` method.

Comment: Hey Thanks, that was it, now I`m getting an other warning, but it might be unrelated :

warning: 'AppDelegate' may not respond to '-presentModalViewController:animated:'

Answer (score 0):

try adding FlipsideViewControllerDelegate to the appDelegate

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate,FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    UIScrollView *scrollView;
    UIPageControl *pageControl;
    NSMutableArray *viewControllers;
    UIView *flipside;

    // To be used when scrolls originate from the UIPageControl
    BOOL pageControlUsed;
}
```